Mathematical Induction: Strong vs Weak Form
I have a rather naive question: The usual mathematical induction works by the same scheme: Let $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ a pos integer and $A(k), n_0 \le k \in \mathbb{N}$ family of statements. Then the "usual" induction states that the statement
"$\forall k \ge n_0: A(k)$ is true" iff $A(n_0)$ is true an for every $k$ the implication "$A(k) $ true" implies "$A(k+1) $ true" is true.
But isn't the stament "$\forall k \ge n_0: A(k)$ is true" true also under weaker condition if we can show that  $A(n_0)$ is true an for every $k$ the implication "$A(d) $ true for all $n_0 \le d \le k$" implies "$A(k+1) $ true" is true?
On other words to show that "$\forall k \ge n_0: A(k)$ is true" for the induction step $k \to k+1$ we can not only assume "$A(k)$ is true" but even "$A(d) $ true for all $n_0 \le d \le k$".
Therefore I'm wondering why to show  "$\forall k \ge n_0: A(k)$ is true" for performing the induction step $k \to k+1$ one usually "torments onerself" assuming "$A(k)$ is true" only instead assuming for sake of simplicity already "$A(d) $ true for all $n_0 \le d \le k$".
Doesn't both methods give (if succeded) the same statement "$\forall k \ge n_0: A(k)$ is true" which we intend to archieve with technically the advantage to perform the induction step under stronger assumptions? In other words, the second "induction" seems to be technically "simpler" to carry out and the result is the same.
So why the "convential" mathematical induction is formulated in first, and not the second way? Where does the devil sits in my reasoning?

Yes, this is sometimes called "strong induction." It follows from regular induction by letting $B(k)$ stand for $\forall n_0\leq n\leq k: A(n)$ and then realize that proving $B(n_0)$ amounts to proving $A(n_0)$ and proving $B(k)\implies B(k+1)$ amounts to proving $B(k)\to A(k+1),$ and that $\forall k\geq n_0: B(k)$ is equivalent to $\forall k\geq n_0: A(k)$

So strong induction is really just a case of regular induction, but for a different statement.

You can generalized that slightly further to get Transfinite induction: If $P$ is a well-ordered set, and you can prove for all $p \in P$ that $(\forall q < p, A(q)) \implies A(p)$, then $A(p)$ is true for all $p \in P$. This is just strong induction on the natural numbers, but it also allows you to do induction on ordinal numbers, using the fact that $A(p)$ is true for all $p \in \Bbb N$ to prove that $A(\omega)$ is also true.

@PaulSinclair: nice, so from viewpoint of this generalization then to formulate induction as "strong" and not "usual or regular"  one is that sense more "natural" (even thought finally they are equivalent, so at the and that seems to be matter of taste as long as one stays in finite caradinalities)

I would say it is because weak induction really has that 'domino stone' feel to it, which for novices really helps to grasp induction and why it works.  And also: for many induction problems weak induction will suffice.
